# Find the number of flags of different types using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> A flagpole is $n$ feet tall. On this pole we display flags of the following types:
>
> - red flags that are $1$ foot tall,
> - blue flags that are $2$ feet tall, and
> - green flags that are $2$ feet tall.
>
> The sum of the heights of the flags is exactly $n$ feet. Let f<sub>n</sub> be the number of ways to display these flags on an $n$ foot tall flagpole.
>
> a) Find $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$
>
> b) Prove that 
>   $$
> f_n = f_{n-1} + 2f_{n-2},  \forall n>=3 \in\mathbb{Z}
> $$
>
> c) Prove by induction on $n$ that
>   $$
> f_n = \frac{2}{3} 2^n + \frac{1}{3} (-1)^n, \forall n>=1 \in\mathbb{Z}.
> $$

Here is what I have done so far:
Based on the comments, Here is answer for part a):

$f_1$ = 1 (only 1 way to fit just 1 red)
$f_2$ = 3 (it is 2 feet, so there are 3 ways we can arrange the flags, either 2red, or 1blue, or 1green)
$f_3$ = 5 (either 3red, or 1red+1blue, 1blue+1red, 1red+1green, 1green+1red)

for $f_3$ we can use: $$
f_n = f_{n-1} + 2f_{n-2},  \forall n>=3 \in\mathbb{Z}
$$ since 3>=3

So, $$f_3 = f_{3-1} + 2f_{3-2}
=> f_2 + 2f_1 => 3 + 2(1) = 5
$$

Comment: I don't think the flag pole starts at 5 feet, you can have just 1 Red flag on a 1ft pole, 2reds / 1b/ 1g on a two foot pole, etc.

Comment: Consider what happens if you were to grow the flagpole by 1 foot - so if the original length were n-1 you would have n-1 arrangements of the n-1 foot section and you'd only be able to add a red flag, you'd have fn-2 arrangements of the n-2 foot section and you could add either a blue or green flag to any of these arrangements.  Now you have to consider the case where you try to add two red flags to the n-2 section, this case is already covered by the n-1 case, so the number of arrangments   fn is then fn-1 + 2fn-2.

Comment: The flagpole is not 5 feet tall. It is $n$ feet tall for some integer $n$ (which need not be 5). You're thinking that there are 1 red flag, 1 blue flag and 1 green flag on the pole, but there may be e.g. several red flags, several blue ones and so on.

Comment: Thanks guys- so the height of the pole is not constant, it can be any n. How do I find f1?

Comment: @cockneywanker can I do this: since fn = fn-1 + 2fn-2 => f1 = f1-1 + 2f1-2 ?

Comment: @cockneywanker I know that f1 = 1 (1 red flag) and f2 = 3 (either 2 red, or 1 blue or 1 green), and f3 = 3 (3 red, 1 red 1 blue, 1 red 1 green). But fn = fn-1 + 2fn-2 => then f1 should be f1-1 + 2f1-2, right?

Comment: First of all, $f_1$ is the number of flag arrangements available for a $1$-foot flagpole. Second of all, you can't say that $$f_n=f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}$$ when $n=1,$ since $1\not\geq 3.$ Third of all, you're miscounting $f_3$, because (for example) $a red flag over a blue flag is a different arrangement than a blue flag over a red flag.

Comment: Thanks @CameronBuie - please see the answer below, is that correct?

Comment: @CameronBuie what if we don't display any flag on 1 foot pole? isn't that another way of arranging them?

Comment: That violates the conditions. The height of the pole must equal the sum of the heights of the displayed flags.

Comment: As for your answer, you're off to a good start!

Comment: @Nitin I had a wrong answer under it, and tried but couldn't remove the answer. So it was marked as answered wrongly. Thats why I added as a new question.

Comment: That's not the way to do things here, Samim.

Comment: Never. Reask. Never. This leads to many kind of problems. I was about to delete this question, when I realized the André had answered it. Merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief answer:  In principle we use strong induction, showing that if $f_k=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^k +\frac{1}{3}\cdot(-1)^k$ for any $k\lt n$, then $f_n=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^n+\frac{1}{3}\cdot (-1)^n$.

Note that $f_n=f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}$. It follows by the induction assumption that
$$f_n=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^{n-1}+\frac{4}{3}\cdot 2^{n-2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot(-1)^{n-1}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot (-1)^{n-2}.$$
Now we simplify. We have 
$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^{n-1}+\frac{4}{3}\cdot 2^{n-2}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^{n-1}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^{n-1}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^n.\tag{1}$$

Also, 
$$\frac{1}{3}\cdot (-1)^{n-1}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot (-1)^{n-2}=\frac{2}{3}\cdot (-1)^n -\frac{1}{3}\cdot (-1)^n=\frac{1}{3}\cdot (-1)^n.\tag{2}$$
Together, (1) and (2) show that $f_n=\frac{2}{3}\cdot 2^n+\frac{1}{3}\cdot (-1)^n$.

**Remark:** It is not clear to me whether you know why the recurrence $f_n=f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}$ holds. Imagine an arrangement of flags of total length $n$. Maybe the top flag is red. It can be followed by any arrangement of flags of total length $n-1$, and there are $f_{n-1}$ of these. Or maybe the top flag is blue or green ($2$ choices). For each choice, that top flag can be followed by any arrangement of flags of total length $n-2$, for a total of $2f_{n-2}$. That shows that $f_n=f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}$.

Comment: thanks ... but how do I do a formal proof for part b? and is my answer for part a correct?

Comment: Your  $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are  correct. Maybe you should have done $f_3$ by direct calculation, since you had not proved the recurrence. My answer gives a pretty detailed description of the induction step. You also need the base steps $f_1$ and $f_2$, but you had done those.

Comment: Nicolas - can you do a formal proof fn = fn-1 + 2fn-2?

Comment: The remark has most of the details of a formal proof.  Many proofs of recurrences are of this type. If you have a specific question about a place where you feel detail is missing, please indicate where, and I will amplify  in a comment.

Comment: Nicolas - I have added the formal proof in your answer, can you check that please?

Comment: I have no objection to it, but feel that the additional detail is not really  needed.  It is clear that you understand that part of the argument.

Comment: Nicolas - thanks a lot. You are awesome :)